# onHover image replace

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm new to javascript and jQuery.

I have a simple script that replaces an image when it is hovered with another one. I want to make one simple change. When hovering is over, the image goes back to the first image.

I would like it to stay unless it is hovered again. I am trying to achieve a loop between 2 images. When you hover once it goes to another image and stays with the second image. When you hover again, this time it goes back to the first image and stays with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/S6pWg/

```
$('#bir').hover(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/2.jpg')
},

function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/1.jpg')
})
```

Comment: please share jsfiddle

Comment: here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/S6pWg/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for you: http://jsfiddle.net/9JM6B/

I added several data-attributes to the image, so you only have one jQuery code for all your images, that should behave like this.

HTML

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/ONE_Campaign.svg" data-alternative="http://digimind.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/number2c.png" data-state="0">
```

jQuery

```
$('img').on('mouseover', function() {
    if( $(this).data('state') == 0 )
    {
        $(this).data('original', $(this).attr('src'));
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('alternative'));
        $(this).data('state','1');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('original'));
        $(this).data('state','0');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose this code:

```
var hoverStatus = 0;
    $('#imgHover').mouseenter(function () {
        if(hoverStatus == 0) {
            $(this).attr('src','http://hasslefreeliving.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/placeholder.gif');
            hoverStatus = 1;
        } else {
            $(this).attr('src','http://www.edrants.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/placeholder.jpg');
            hoverStatus = 0;
        }
    });
```

You could of course use another attribute like "hoverStatus" instead of an extra variable

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2YcYG/

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this

```
    var hoverStatus =0;


   $('#bir').hover(function(){
       if(hoverStatus ==0)
       {
            $(this).attr('src','img/2.jpg');
            hoverStatus =1;
       }
       else 
      {
           $(this).attr('src','img/1.jpg');
           hoverStatus =0;
      }
    },
    function(){

    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here we are using two image variables and changing images on mouseenter event.

```
var img1 = 'http://www.pizzatower.com/img/icons/Pizza-icon.png';

var img2 = 'http://danosdelivers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/danos-supreme-pizza-2-256x256.jpg';

$('#bir').mouseenter(function () {
    var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
    if(currentImg == img1)
        currentImg = img2;
    else
        currentImg = img1;
    $(this).attr('src',currentImg);
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/S6pWg/7/) is the working JSFiddle.